# Unable to open Gii in Yii Framework on localhost

Tags: yii2, localhost, gii

I am trying to open the gii module on my yii based project on localhost. But its not opening. I am using virtual hosts to access the project (http://pys.dev not http://localhost/pys.dev).

```
if (YII_ENV_DEV) {
// configuration adjustments for 'dev' environment
$config['bootstrap'][] = 'debug';
$config['modules']['debug'] = [
    'class' => 'yii\debug\Module',
    'allowedIPs' => ['127.0.0.2'],
];

$config['bootstrap'][] = 'gii';
$config['modules']['gii'] = [
    'class' => 'yii\gii\Module',
];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you trying to access it? If you enabled pretty URLs then it should be http://domain/gii if not then http://domain/index.php?r=gii

Also check in your `web/index.php` that `YII_ENV` is set to `dev`

Comment: I was trying to access it using r=going even though pretty URL is enabled. It's my first time working on yii framework. This solves my problem. Thank you